# Matching default color in custom preference

Tags: android, xml, colors, preference

I have a custom preference that is basically a slider.
The custom XML for the preference slider can be used to set text color, but I need to MATCH the text color to the default that the device uses.  The Title color seems fine, just uses default (same as another CheckBoxPreference title, or so it looks).  The Summary color is also using the default color (same as Title), but I want this to match the default color of the Summary text of a CheckBoxPreference, which is defined right above it in XML.

Can I get the color of the Summary text from the CheckBoxPreference and just change the Summary text color of the custom preference to match the CheckBoxPreference Summary color, or is there a global (R.attr.xxxxxxxx whatever) that I can use that exists on all devices?

For example, I have a checkbox preference that does not specify title or summary colors - thus, it uses the default color scheme (but this color scheme *looks* like the title matches, but the summary text in the custom preference (from xml) is the same as the title color, but not the default summary color as default preferences)).

My custom slider (which has title and summary fields) needs to match the default OS colors for those two fields to the device default color scheme for those entries (title & summary).

1. How do I get the default device color that is set for a checkboxpreference when no color is specified?
2. How do I assign that color to my *custom* preference, which has it's own xml file that defines the custom preference view.

Hope this makes perfect sense, if not I'll elaborate a bit more.

preference definition for the custom preference (which is further defined in it's xml):

```
<com.xxx.sbp.SeekBarPref
    android:id="@+id/xmlpreference_seekbar"
    android:key="preference_seekbar"
    android:title="Seek Bar Pref"
    android:summary="Choose seconds"
    android:defaultValue="20"
    android:max="300"
    sbp:min="10"
    sbp:interval="10"
    sbp:intervaldivide="10"
    sbp:unitsLeft=""
    sbp:unitsRight="s" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I found these: `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"` and `android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"` seem to do the trick.

Comment: I'll give these a shot, assuming maybe they include color and not just text appearance.  Will reply when I know.  Thanks.

Comment: This does not solve the problem, it changes nothing for text color of summary attribute.

Answer (score 0):

A complicated solution is given in [Android preferences summary default color?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4081946/android-preferences-summary-default-color)

I agree with the respondents to above that neither of the textAppearance settings will guarantee a color match.

Answer (score 0):

The default color for preference summary text appears to be `#DACC45`. The way I did this was to take a screen snapshot and query the colored pixels with an image editor.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem and I've solved it with these lines in `onCreateView` method of `seekBarPreference.java`

```
TextView summaryText = new TextView(getContext());
summaryText.setText(getSummary());
summaryText.setTextAppearance(getContext(), android.R.style.TextAppearance_Small);
```