# How can I change the summary text color of a Preference programmatically?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, preferences, preferenceactivity, textcolor

I am trying to change the text color of a Preference when the user input a incorrect value, similar as web forms do. I found in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4126904/1612432) how to access the text view of the summary but the color is not being changed. The code I am using is this:

```
LinearLayout ly = (LinearLayout) userPasswordPref.getView(null, getListView());
TextView summarytv = (TextView) ((RelativeLayout) ly.getChildAt(1)).getChildAt(1);
summarytv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
```

`UserPasswordPref` is of type `Preference`. How could I change the color?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a solution, I have had to create a layout with the following code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/title"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/summary"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/red" />

</LinearLayout>
```

An then, in my code:

```
userPasswordPref.setLayoutResource(R.layout.summary_error);
userPasswordPref.setSummary(R.string.error_summary);
```

Where `userPasswordPref` is a `Preference`, and `summary_error` is the layout above.

**Source**: [elbauldelprogramador](https://elbauldelprogramador.com/en/cambiar-el-color-del-summary-en-una-preferencia-android/)